# Determining isometric depth

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus

I have an array of points bounded by $width \times height$ that can be plotted on a plane like so for $width = 3, height = 3$;

```
(0,2)  (1,2)  (2,2)


(0,1)  (1,1)  (2,1)


(0,0)  (1,0)  (2,0)
```

I then translate these points so they are arranged as follows, however I keep a refrence original co-ordinates.  Doing so, I am able to order the points as belonging to specific depth, noted by $z$, such that the very bottom point is considered $0$;

```
                (0,2)                       z=4

        (0,1)           (1,2)               z=3

(0,0)           (1,1)           (2,2)       z=2

        (1,0)           (2,1)               z=1

                (2,0)                       z=0
```

I've determined that the following solves $z$ when $width=height$;

$x - y + \left(\frac{width + height}{2}\right) -1$

However, this does not work for $width \neq height$.

Also I note that the following solves $z$ only when $width=1$;

$x - y + \left(\frac{width + height}{2}\right) + \left(\frac{height-3}{2}\right)$

How can I solve $z$ for a given $(x,y)$ for any $width \times height$?

Comment: Replace $(\text{width}+\text{height})/2$ with just $\text{height}$.

Comment: Embarassing how long I was stuck on this - @Rahul you're totally right.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the second arrangement rotates the first arrangement clockwise by half of a right angle. In that case, let $w$ denote width, $x$ denote the first coordinate of a point, and $y$ denote the second coordinate of a point (you seem to have reversed $x$ and $y$ but I'm using them in the idiomatic way). Note that for $z=0$, $y-x$ is $1-w$ and for every unit increase in $z$, $y-x$ increases by one. Therefore $z = y - x + 1 - w$. This formula should work for every width and height.

Comment: This formula does not work when width > height.  For example, when for $x = 0, y = 2, w = 4$, then $z = -1$ but the constraint $z >= 0$ exists.